# SELECT * FROM combination in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, command

This is my MySQL databse:

```
+-----+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+
| id  | data       | hora     | conexoes_total | conexoes_sim | conexoes_lentas |
+-----+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+
|   1 | 2013-11-18 | 00:00:02 |            200 |            1 |              30 |
|   2 | 2013-11-18 | 10:15:03 |             14 |            2 |              25 |
|   3 | 2013-11-18 | 10:30:03 |             53 |            3 |              25 |
|   4 | 2013-11-18 | 10:45:02 |             60 |            5 |              26 |
|   5 | 2013-11-18 | 11:00:02 |             66 |            3 |              27 |
|   6 | 2013-11-18 | 11:15:03 |             74 |            5 |              27 |
                                         .
                                         .
                                         .
```

I want select * from every 00:00:% data and the last value inserted..
I already know how to select the midnight values: `SELECT * FROM audiencia WHERE hora LIKE '00:00:%';`, and this what i got:

```
+-----+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+
| id  | data       | hora     | conexoes_total | conexoes_sim | conexoes_lentas |
+-----+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+
|   1 | 2013-11-18 | 00:00:02 |            200 |            1 |              30 |
|  57 | 2013-11-19 | 00:00:02 |            446 |            1 |              97 |
| 153 | 2013-11-20 | 00:00:02 |            300 |            3 |             173 |
| 349 | 2013-11-21 | 00:00:02 |             42 |            2 |              94 |
+-----+------------+----------+----------------+--------------+-----------------+
```

But now i want to show the last value inserted in table together with the above result..
How can i manage a command to do that to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(SELECT * FROM audiencia WHERE hora LIKE '00:00:%')
UNION
(SELECT * FROM audiencia ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: It returns only the last value.

Comment: Add brackets and it works....Thx u Thomas:
(SELECT * FROM audiencia WHERE hora LIKE '00:00:%') UNION (SELECT * FROM audiencia ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);  Edit your answer plz.

Comment: One Like from me for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to fetch the last value inserted for column **hora** of table **audiencia** which starts from **00:00:** ?

If Answer to the above question is YES, then the below SQL will solve your problem.

*SELECT * FROM audiencia WHERE hora LIKE '00:00:%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;*

In case the answer to the above question is NO, then I might have not understood the requirement properly. Kindly, please explain the requirement.

Thanks,
Abhijit

Comment: Great that you solved it.. Can you please share the solution.

Comment: Thomas Ruiz's answer... :)

Comment: Sorry for that comment :) Got the answer.